# AngularJS- Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! in a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing a snipped to evaluate users answer. If his answer is right, then I'm appending a correct icon in the end. I've created a custom directive to evaluate the answer. But I keep encountering the infamous **Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!** error.

Here is a snapshot of my partial,

```
    <li ng-repeat="answer in practice.currentQuestion.answers" class="answer">
            <label class="radio multiple answer-body" evaluate-me is-correct="{'isCorrect': answer.isCorrect}" >
                <div class="answer-body pull-left" ng-bind-html-unsafe="answer.body|removeemptyparagraphs"></div>
            </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and this my directive,

```
app.directive('evaluateMe', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        scope:{
            answer: '=isCorrect'
        },
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var prepend;
            console.log(scope.answer.isCorrect);
            if(scope.answer.isCorrect){
                prepend = '<i class="student-sprite-1-right-icon-for-qus pull-right"></i>';
            }else{
                prepend = '<i class="student-sprite-1-cancel-icon-for-qus pull-right"></i>';
            }
            element.append(prepend);
        }
    };
});
```

It's my understanding that, this error happens when you're incorrectly updating the model from the view or in the middle of a loop. But in this case, I'm just evaluating the model. And the wierdest part is the directive execution completes and appends my HTML string inside the DOM. the error happens after that(Please refer to the screenshot)

[image]

NOTE: I've referred to the other posts, but I'm not able to figure out a solution.

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: can you post your code in Fiddle/Plunker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help you (a fiddle/plunk would be useful) but:

1) You are adding unecessary complexity to the variable passed to the directive; try:

```
<label class="radio multiple answer-body" evaluate-me answer="answer">
```

and in the code:

```
scope:{
    answer: '='
},
```

Or if you only want to pass the `isCorrect` flag:

```
<label class="radio multiple answer-body" evaluate-me is-correct="answer.isCorrect">
```

and in the code:

```
scope:{
    isCorrect: '='
},
```

And then use `scope.isCorrect` directly.

---

Could you also give a try to a directive using transclusion, that does not need the DOM manipulation logic, preferring Angular templates instead:

```
app.directive('evaluateMe', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        template: 
            "<div>" +
                "<div ng-transclude></div>" +
                "<i ng-class=\"{" +
                    "'student-sprite-1-right-icon-for-qus': isCorrect, " +
                    "'student-sprite-1-cancel-icon-for-qus': !isCorrect" +
                "}\" class=\"pull-right\"></i>"
            "</div>",
        transclude: true,
        scope:{
            isCorrect: '='
        }
    };
});
```

Used as:

```
<label class="radio multiple answer-body" evaluate-me is-correct="answer.isCorrect">
    <div any content here-it will be transcluded></div>
</label>
```

Comment: Transclude suggestuin  worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch :)